# react-select not setting defaultValue param properly

Tags: reactjs, react-select

So I have this piece of code, and somehow it's not setting the defaultValue properly, here's the value of patchsOptions[0]:

`console.log(patchOptions[0]); // Object { value: "10.15.1", label: "10.15.1" }`

```
<Select
    className="col-2"
    placeholder="Patch"
    defaultValue={patchsOptions[0]}
    options={patchsOptions}
    onChange={option => this.onChangePatch(option.value)}
/>
```

The default value keeps empty, but the options are loaded correctly, so I didn't see the problem since looking at some examples, it also uses the "options[0]" variable.

By changing the code this way, it works as expected:

```
<Select
    className="col-2"
    placeholder="Patch"
    defaultValue={{ value: 'test', label: 'test' }}
    options={patchsOptions}
    onChange={option => this.onChangePatch(option.value)}
/>
```

They both have the same obj structure, so I didn't get where's the problem. I logged the default value before rendering, and it's setting normally, it's not empty.

Comment: probably patchsOptions[0] is empty in the first time, post the code of patchsOptions

Comment: Did you log `patchsOptions[0]` before retuning the JSX? Is that not empty?

Comment: The options come from the state, I just map it to fit the label/value structure the lib uses before rendering. I logged the patchsOptions[0] before rendering and it's not empty

Comment: here's the full code https://pastebin.com/8ubEJg8M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the patchesOptions is set from an Async call, then the first render time it will be null, and the defaultValue doesn't change if you change it's value, this is like an initial value, so what you can do is to use value option, and link it to the selectedPatch, also I did some change (**onChange**) like this:

```
<Select
    className="col-2"
    placeholder="Patch"
    value={{this.state.selectedPatch.value, this.state.selectedPatch.label}}
    options={patchsOptions}
    onChange={option => this.onChangePatch(option)}
/>
```

Comment: You mean that the fact that is indeed first rendering as null, it will be set as null even though the app is rendered again with the change of any state?

What small change do you mean? I tested using value instead of defaultValue and it works, but the front-end wont let me select another option, but the state itself changes normally since it's being updated by the onChange event

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer.
regarding selecting another option, did you change (onChange) as I've done? if yes then maybe the (option) is not the one required to be passed to OnChangePatch function, maybe something nested, debug it and check what's the option is, and then pass the correct object to onChangePatch

Comment: It did work when passing the state directly instead of the variables, thanks man!